# Laravel config subfolder not recognized on new server

Tags: heroku, deployment, laravel, laravel-4

I have some config files of US state counties, for example:

```
config/
    state/
        alabama/
            counties.php
        alaska/
            counties.php
        ...
```

And on my development localhost server, I call them with:

```
Config::get('state/alabama/counties');
```

and it works, it loads an array of counties which I display somewhere.

But when I deploy this app on the Heroku, they won't show up.
    I was thinking that it maybe has a problem with treating the `config/state/`subfolder as an environment config?

I do have a `config/staging` subfolder, in which I have new DB config stuff, and it works with no problem,
    but on the Heroku app, the states just won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this directory to your autoload mapping in `composer.json` and then run `composer dump-autoload`?  Without this, Laravel doesn't know to load your new files in to consideration.

Composer is a CLI-run file that exists in the Root of each laravel installation.  `composer.json` is the config file for Composer - it uses this to manage your dependencies.

There's a section in `composer.json` called "autoload."  These are the files that will automatically be loaded each time the app boots.  Mine looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/core"
        ]
```

For each folder that didn't exist before and that I wanted Laravel to understand, I added an entry here.  Then, I ran `composer dump-autoload` and Laravel "understood" where the files I wanted to use were.

Each time you add a file, class, repository - anything that you want Laravel to automatically use, you'll have to run `composer dump-autoload`.

P.S: If `composer dump-autoload` doesn't work, try `composer.phar dump-autoload`.

Comment: Can you please give me some reference about this? Just want to point out that the config files are working on localhost, but on the Heroku server.

Comment: This should help - it's Heroku specific: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/using_composer_to_manage_dependencies_in_heroku_php_apps/